# Passing directive as props

Tags: solid-js

For example I have a simple directive like this:

```js
export const inputLogger = (el: HTMLInputElement) => {
    const onInput = (e: Event) => {
        console.log((e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement).value)
    }

    el.addEventListener("input", onInput);
};
```

and my component looks like this

```js
const CustomInput: Component<JSX.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> = (props) => {
  return <input {...props} />
}

function Counter() {
  return (
    <>
      <CustomInput use:inputLogger  />  {/* directive is not being used */}
      <br />
      <input use:inputLogger /> {/* directive works properly */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Seems like `inputLogger` directive doesn't work properly when being passed as a prop to other component, but works fine when passed to a native input element.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround for this or is this a limitation from Solid.js?

[Playground Example](https://playground.solidjs.com/?version=1.4.1#NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGGUCWEwBowBcCeADgsrgM4Ae2YZA9gK4BOAxiWGjIbY7gAQi9GcCABM4jXgF9eAM0a0YvADo1aAGzQiAtACsyAegDucAEYqA3EogcuPfrwDCCrhGG4svAFIBlABpTZeUUVOg1tPQsrG24+EAxCelwAGVoAc1TxaTkFZTAAOn14xJT08UiIK2ZaCDI+B3pahQBJCATcREdnarcAHh9fPJa2gAkAFQBZJIBBXFxGNBNEuDIescmhxIBRNTh4CFwAPgPeAF5eAApCeUIyAEpT45ArXkE4XCYIXh6i2Ly-q9oN2k+gOVkkVisMnoEGYuDQ1U60Nw4nO9yen1e70Yn3OzxeX1BGPxX3qjRgGz4DTgiB+JQyEl4IJeIH0ACpeCI0EJYWgAG5wXhoMi8CC0PgmOAYVK8KkiXis-Tgon4nomCQgvHE76tRIysjU2lpemMx5sjlcuA8-m8QzcADWwoBxEYanw8sVmq+Goxt0sECVViEohRqIeJIY+3EJo8IlozHoe1weQyuG2uzcACF8E0RLiwFBCIQVLcAIS+qxgSRYcDQeBIdg65JG8TUAjEevkKg4OhMVj1uAUWx8Ko1PiG0oSM7nOBqDprJIUtOJ+4nR5KRieke1XjVCmnC7U3ibfn7FdrjcVXBKXBb9RwPJqNLnad5eOMIO4UZQRgp3hQYXzouOzLnkvJQGo9BwLc64Qrg4IXjBl4znkUAiCIx5uEkQrIq4jB5j8KgeLujblhekiWBelYALpAA)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in Solid, directives can only be applied to native elements, not to components. See here: https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/bindings_directives.

You can also use a pattern like this, but you no longer can rely on spreading props.

```
const CustomInput: Component<JSX.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> = (
  props
) => {
  return <input {...props} ref={props["use:inputLogger"]} />;
};

function Counter() {
  return (
    <>
      <CustomInput use:inputLogger={inputLogger} />
    </>
  );
}
```

https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-51759678&version=1.4.1